# Why useless Lambda function is still be called

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an old AWS lambda function not working now.
It was originally created to work in conjunction with AWS Config.
Currently, it is not used in conjunction with AWS Config.
Also, the only opportunity to calling is AWS Config.
However, there are still calls to Lambda functions in CloudWatch Logs.
I tryed to troubleshoot identifying the cause of this call, but failed.
Is there any possibility CloudWatchMetrics itself call lambda function and had calling logs?
Please advise what is the cause or where to check to find reason.

Comment: You can examine AWS CloudTrail to determine how the AWS Lambda function is being invoked.

Comment: If not already done, modify the Lambda function to log the event and context objects. It may help you determine what triggered the Lambda function.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your advice, I checked CloudTrail and find logs.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your comment, I will try to modify Lambda function to log the event and context objects.

Comment: @jarmod After modify Lambda function to log the event, I found problem and solved. Thank you very much for your advice!!